# Changing the systemNavigationBarColor isn't working Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, themes

I want to change the color of the systemNavigationBar based on the theme.

I have been trying to change the color of the system navigation color of the app using the `SystemOverlayStyle` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 ThemeData get light => ThemeData(
        
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          iconTheme: lightBase.iconTheme,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 17,
            color: AppColors.textDark,
          ),
           systemOverlayStyle:
              SystemUiOverlayStyle(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.pink),
        ),
        
      );
```

Output: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `Scaffold` with [`AnnotatedRegion`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnnotatedRegion-class.html) widget. Then set it's value property to `SystemUIOverlayStyle`

For Example

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white, // Change Background color
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,  // Change Icon color
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
```

To change dynamically, for example with system theme, first get the `Brightness` of your system.

```dart
 var brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
 bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
```

Now based on `isDarkMode` value

```
systemNavigationBarColor:isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
```

Comment: Thank you , But i want the color dynamic , so this wont help me thanks

Comment: You want to change color on button press?

Comment: No according the system theme

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: `var brightness = SchedulerBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;`
    `bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;` worked for me .

Comment: not work any more

Answer (score 0):

use manifest.xml file( in android project)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setNavigationBarColor(int)

Comment: I want to have different color based on the theme!

Comment: use android java / kotlin code  getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);